# Temperature controller bypassed on old Traulsen refrigerator

Tags: refrigerator

I have an old (1976) Traulsen RRI 2-32 L UT commercial refrigerator that gets used for 1 month a year to hang beef. It runs very consistently at 39.5F, but I want it down to 35. Looks like it has been converted from R-12 to R134A at some point. The compressor seems to cycle on and off as expected but I think the circulation fans are running constantly.

I was figuring out how to adjust it and noticed the back of the temperature control dial was bypassed (both wires hooked to same side). At first I assumed there was some other temp controller elsewhere in the system, but we can't find one anywhere. I got to thinking I should just replace it with a new digital inkbird controller which I'm fine with, but a few concerns:

1. How is it maintaining a consistent temperature right now? Does it switch just off pressure and that's consistent enough?
2. Did someone bypass that controller because it was broken and just wanted to keep it running, or was that from the R134A conversion and they work differently?
3. If the temp controller is constantly "on" (ie closed switch) because it's bypassed, adding a new one can surely only make the unit warmer, not colder? ie I suspect I could make it maintain 42 degrees, but not 35.
4. If the temp controller is constantly "on" (ie closed switch) I would think it should be running much colder unless something else is wrong. The "pressure switch" unit looks adjustable, but no idea if that's safe or what to set it to.

Disclaimer, I'm fairly mechanical and have a mechanic friend who can work on automotive AC, but have very little context in this kind of unit.

Comment: I got this running by tweaking the pressure settings lower and also found one evaporator fan was dead, which I replaced. Installed a digital thermostat control for $30 (Ketotech from Amazon) and now it all works well!